# Aliasing Input Control Labels

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm currently working on an input control that uses the SQL Wildcard '%' and the `iLike` function because my input control uses SQL code to pull back. Now, when I want to display the parameter on my `Title` band I want it to display my choice of words in replacement of the '%' I'm using as the parameter. Is there any way to alias `$P{param_name}` to something else when it equals something that I define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your current title band contains a text field with the Text Field Expression `$P{param_name}`.

In order to filter out the wild card you could just change the Text Field Expression to something like `"%".equals($P{param_name}) ? "All Values" : ("Filtered for '" + $P{param_name} +"'")`.

If the `$P{param_name}` contains `%` it shows *All Values*, otherwise *Filtered for '{selected value}'* is shown.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. Do you mind me asking if it's possible to do the same thing on the Input Controls? So, instead of it showing `%`, `Item2`, and `Item3`; It will show `All Values`, `Item2`, and `Item3`

Comment: what is your input control query? It would need to be sovled on query level. e.g. with `select f1 as id, f2 as value UNION select '%', 'All Values'`.